# chr in python 2 is acting strange

Tags: python, python-2.7, ascii, python-unicode

Looking at the `chr` documentation in **Python 2.7**:

> Return a string of one character whose ASCII code is the integer i.

[source](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#chr)

but ASCII is in range of 128. Yet in Python 2.7, I have:

```
> chr(181)
'\xb5
```

This is surprising, I expected an error. I will just accept this for now.

In **Python 3.7**:

> Return the string representing a character whose Unicode code point is the integer i.

[source](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#chr)

So basically this is `unichr` in Python 2.7.

In **Python 3.7**:

```
> chr(181).encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xb5' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Which is expected, and then:

```
> chr(181).encode('utf8')
b'\xc2\xb5'
```

Note how we have the `\xb5` in common.

*Question*:

Why does Python 2.7 not break on `chr(181)` and how come it actually outputs what seems to be a partially correct encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `chr()` accepts a range of 0..255.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr):
*Return a string of one character whose ASCII code is the integer i. For example, chr(97) returns the string 'a'. This is the inverse of ord(). The argument must be in the range [0..255], inclusive; ValueError will be raised if i is outside that range. See also unichr().*

Comment: Thank you! But...  that is not ascii. Also that is a big difference between py 2 and 3, not much surprised there tbh. And also, what is that partial result py2 is returning?

Comment: It simply returns the number in hexadecimal!
hex(181) = 0xb5

Comment: Thank you very much. This is strange indeed. I will accept this as the answer. But if you, or anyone reading has information about the history of this or the design decisions, an email thread whatnot, I will be very interested and much obliged.

Comment: Could be related to backward compitability to unicode, such that throughputs still work to UTF-8 and will not crash.